# jQuery Listview Formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been working on a listview and I am able format it correct using jQuery statically, but when I try to populate data pragmatically, the formatting does not apply.

```
var resetList = '<ul id="list" data-role="listview" >';

        function getItems(){
                console.log("Get stations");
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(locOnSuccess, locOnError);
                document.getElementById('scroller').innerHTML = resetList;
                refreshList();

            }

            function processResult(){

                if(httpResponse.readyState==4 && httpResponse.status==200){
                    var result = jQuery.parseJSON(httpResponse.responseText);
                    for(var x = 0; x < result.stations.length; x++){
                        var var1 = result.stations[x].var1;
                        var var2 = result.stations[x].var2;
                        var var3 = result.stations[x].var3;
                        var var4 = result.stations[x].var4;
                        var var5 = result.stations[x].var5;
                        var var6 = result.stations[x].var6;

                        createListItem(var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6);
                        refreshList();
                    }
                }
            }

    function refreshList(){
                    $("list").listview().listview('refresh');
    }

    function createListItem(var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6){
        var listItem = '<li><h2>' + var1 + '</h2><span class="ui-li-aside">' + var2 + '</span> <h4>' + var3 + '</h4><p>' + var4 + '</p></li>';
        document.getElementById('list').innerHTML += listItem;
    }
```

New Code

```
var resetList = '<ul id="list" data-role="listview" >';

            function getItems(){
                    console.log("Get stations");
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(locOnSuccess, locOnError);
                    document.getElementById('scroller').innerHTML = resetList;
                    refreshList();

                }

                function processResult(){

                    if(httpResponse.readyState==4 && httpResponse.status==200){
                        var result = jQuery.parseJSON(httpResponse.responseText);
                        for(var x = 0; x < result.stations.length; x++){
                            var var1 = result.stations[x].var1;
                            var var2 = result.stations[x].var2;
                            var var3 = result.stations[x].var3;
                            var var4 = result.stations[x].var4;
                            var var5 = result.stations[x].var5;
                            var var6 = result.stations[x].var6;

                            createListItem(var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6);
                            refreshList();
                        }
                    }
                }

        function createListItem(var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6){
            $('list').append('<li><h2>' + var1 + '</h2><span class="ui-li-aside">' + var2 + '</span> <h4>' + var3 + '</h4><p>' + var4 + '</p></li>').listview().listview('refresh');
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out by using

`$('list').append('<li><h2>' + var1 + '</h2><span class="ui-li-aside">' + var2 + '</span> <h4>' + var3 + '</h4><p>' + var4 + '</p></li>').listview().listview('refresh');`

Updated code above.